# Create Installment Button

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

We want to create an installment plan button using the button manager SDK, but we are getting this error message:

```
'ShortMessage' => 'SignUp for the Enhanced Recurring Payments package required.',
'LongMessage' => 'You need to have PayPal Business account and the Enhanced Recurring Payments package to create Automatic Billing or Installment Plan button.',
'ErrorCode' => '13110'
```

How and where can I enable that feature in sandbox mode and in live mode?

Comment: www.paypal.com/mts <- create a ticket here

Answer (score 0):

Sign up in the sandbox here: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_product-go&product=premium_services

Log in with your test account email/password (something like aaaaaa_############_biz@emaildomain.com )

For your live account you can go here: https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/erp_overview